# How do I create a pie slice shape on Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'd like to create or find this shape on Draw.io, a pie shape that can be adjusted, size, length, etc.

[image: Pie Shape]

I couldn't find this shape in the shapes list, so I figure this one must be created somehow, but I don't know how, especially with such a curvy shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- pie shape is located in **Basic** shapes:

[image: 3]

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was adjustable. I thought it was just a straight-up pac-man shape, and you couldn't turn it into a one-slice like a pizza slice. Thanks.